# How to add the Zoom effect on our own website

Tags: facebook

I would like to have the effect like Facebook Theatre Mode on my website. But where to find the sample? I need one, the effect is when we click on the photo from the photo album then another pop-out layer on the top of the website. It is something like this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31FG9yONqVo 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elioihkkcdgakfbahdoddophfngopipi

But I only get the code to disable it and not full code.![A white pop-up layer display above the web page. Anyone has any idea how to do this or any example for me to follow? Truly need help and appreciate much for helping!][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help from the below scripts or adapt as per your need...
http://www.intenseblog.com/design/8-amazing-javascript-image-zoom-scripts.html